# Microsoft Outlook Inbox Repair Tool keeps popping up

Tags: windows, exchange-2010, outlook, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

I ran into this weird issue with one of my users.  Microsoft Outlook Inbox Repair Tool keeps popping up every time she starts Outlook, even after the repair is done, the Outlook still won't start.  At this point, I just want to suppress it.

**Here is some info:**

1. It's a Windows 10 machine
2. We are using Office 365
3. We are running Exchange 2010

**Here is what I have done:**

1. Removed and re-installed O365
2. Used Microsoft removal tool to completely remove O365 and then re-installed it
3. Went through the repair several times
4. Removed her mail profile and created a new one
5. Tried running different Outlook commands (Outlook /safe, etc.)

It's still pulls up the Microsoft Outlook Inbox Repair Tool.  I am at a bit of a loss here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue occurs if this user starts Outlook on another computer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\PST
```

and make sure the `REG_DWORD` for `PromptRepair` is set to `0` and not `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one similar thread "**[Outlook won't start, says data file corrupted, but deleted data file](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/outlook-wont-start-says-data-file-corrupted-but/cda168db-0106-469f-a33f-538d26bbfb42)**" for your reference, according to **tconrady**'s solution in the thread, you could try to modify/add the following registry keys to fix the **Repair Tool** issue:

- Delete all profiles:
  ***Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles***
- Modify/Add the keys **LastCorruptStore**(Remove the file specified - **Value Data**)
  & **PromptRepair**(Key type: **REG_DWORD**, value data: **1**):
  ***Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\PST***